# Tem como fazer useState alterar imediatamente?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou chamando uma API, e com esta resposta preciso das informações necessárias para gerar um PDF, porém quando coloco a resposta numa variável `useState`, ela vem nula na primeira renderização, então não consigo passar ela imediatamente, esta função é executado no meu de botão submit, então não posso usar o useEffect pois é feito somente após o clique no botão. Sou iniciante ainda em react.

Dúvida: Existe alguma forma para que consiga pegar as informações já na primeira renderização ou alguma condição?

```js
async function criarPDF() {

  const resp = await api.post('/consumidor/id/prods', {
    consumidor_id: response.data
  });

  setconsProdNfe(resp.data);

  const prods = [];

  consProdNfe.map(el => el.tb_ConsumidorProdutosNves.map(infos => {
    prods.push({
      modelo: infos.tb_ProdutoNfe.modelo,
      quantidadeUsada: infos.quantidadeUsada,
      numero: infos.numero
    });

    return prods;
  }));

  if (prods.length > 0) { //Não entra nesta condição pois sempre renderiza vazio primeiro
    await api.post('/create/pdf', {
      prods: prods,
    }, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.data.error) {
        console.error(response.data.error)
      }

      const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const fileLink = document.createElement('a');
      fileLink.href = fileURL;
      const fileName = response.headers['content-disposition'].substring(22, 52);
      fileLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
      fileLink.click();
      fileLink.remove();
    }).catch(error => {
      alert("Não foi possível emitir o PDF.");
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `hook useEffect`

```
  const [prods, setProds] = useState(null);
  
  //esta função será chamada quando houver alteração na variavel de estado (prods)
  useEffect(() => {
     const handleCreatePdf = () {
       // implemente a requisição de criar o pdf 
     }
     handleCreatePdf();
  }, [prods])
```